# How to create Square Customer with Node.js and Unirest

Tags: node.js, square-connect, unirest

I am trying to create a new Square user, but am having problems.  I was able to use Unirest to GET a Square customer list at the `https://connect.squareup.com/v2/customers` endpoint, but haven't been able to successfully POST.

```
const unirest = require('unirest');
const access_token = 'sq-123...';

var createCustomer = 
unirest.post('https://connect.squareup.com/v2/customers')
  .headers({
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token})
  .send({
    "email_address": "abc@example.com"
  })
  .end(function (createCustomer) {
    console.log(createCustomer);
});
```

The response returns

```
raw_body: 
'{"errors":[{
"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR",
"code":"BAD_REQUEST",
"detail":"invalid character \'e\' looking for beginning of value (line 1, character 1)"}]}' }
```

I also tried using `.field` instead of `.send`, which returned

```
raw_body: '{"errors":
[{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR",
"code":"BAD_REQUEST",
"detail":"invalid character \'-\' in numeric literal (line 1, character 2)"}]}' }
```

Is it possible to create a customer using Unirest and Node?  If so, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try sending `Content-Type: application/json` header to let the server know that data is of type json. You can use `type` of unirest also, e.g. `unireset.post().headers().type('json').send..`

Comment: OK, that worked using the ```.send``` command.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will POST

```
const unirest = require('unirest');
const access_token = 'sq-123...';

var createCustomer = 
unirest.post('https://connect.squareup.com/v2/customers')
  .headers({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token})
  .send({
    "email_address": "abc@example.com"
  })
  .end(function (createCustomer) {
    console.log(createCustomer);
});
```